# How do I switch form function based on switch case?

Tags: javascript, html, function, switch-statement

I've been able to change my header and directions using switch for my distance converter, and I have written out the functions for converting both mi to km and km to mi, but I'm not sure how to get the appropriate function linked to the convert distance button once I've pressed either k or m. Any help would be terrific! :)

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Miles to Kilometers Converter</title>

<!--/ /-------- Normalize CSS --------/ /-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--/ /-------- Google Fonts --------/ /-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!--/ /-------- My Styles --------/ /-->
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Miles to Kilometers Converter</h1>

    <div class="container top">
        <p>Type in a number of miles and click the button to convert the distance to kilometers.</p>

        <form id="convert">

            <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" placeholder="distance">
            <input type="button" name="convertdist" value="Convert Distance" onclick="convert()">

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container bottom" id="answer">
        <h2 class="invisible"></h2>
    </div>

    <p id="directions">Press the "K" key to switch to kilometer converstion, press the "M" key to switch to mile conversion</p>


<script>

function convert(){

            var miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
            var kilometers = (miles * 1.609344);
            var answer = document.createElement("H2");
            answer.innerHTML = `${miles} miles converts to ${kilometers.toFixed(3)} kilometers`;
            document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);

          if (isNaN(kilometers)){
              answer.innerHTML = `Enter a number you clown!`;

          }
}

      function convert(){

            var miles = (kilometers * 0.621371);
            var kilometers = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
            var answer = document.createElement("H2");
            answer.innerHTML = `${kilometers} kilometers converts to ${miles.toFixed(3)} miles`;
            document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);

          if (isNaN(miles)){
              answer.innerHTML = `Enter a number you clown!`;


var header = document.querySelector("H1");
var directions = document.querySelector("P");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){

    var keyPressed = event.which;


    switch(keyPressed){
        case 77:header.innerHTML = "MILES TO KILOMETERS CONVERTER";
                directions.innerHTML = "Type in a number of miles and click the button to convert the distance to kilometers.";
                break;
        case 75:header.innerHTML = "KILOMETERS TO MILES CONVERTER";
                directions.innerHTML = "Type in a number of kilometers and click the button to convert the distance to miles.";
                break;
        //default: alert("Please press K or M for conversion");
        }
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried putting the functions under the appropriate case but to no avail. I'm new to all of this, please be kind. I'm still learning javascript and have only one quarter of HTML and CSS to lean on. :)

Comment: this is a very serious piece of line in your code.. no one does that.. >>Enter a number you clown!<< validation has to be done by you. when u test the code, we try with all the possibilities which could go south. it's your responsibility as a developer to handle those kind of exceptions and you are not suppose to call the user a clown because he did something stupid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code. I hope it'll help you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Miles to Kilometers Converter</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Miles to Kilometers Converter</h1>
    <div class="container top">
        <p>Type in a number of miles and click the button to convert the distance to kilometers.</p>
        <form id="convert">
            <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" placeholder="distance">
            <input type="button" name="convertdist" value="Convert Distance" id="convert_btn">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container bottom" id="answer">
        <h2 class="invisible"></h2>
    </div>
    <p id="directions">Press the "K" key to switch to kilometer converstion, press the "M" key to switch to mile conversion</p>
<script>
    var km = true;
    function convertKM(){
        var miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
        var kilometers = (miles * 1.609344);
        var answer = document.createElement("H2");
        answer.innerHTML = `${miles} miles converts to ${kilometers.toFixed(3)} kilometers`;
        document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);
        if (isNaN(kilometers)){
            answer.innerHTML = `Enter a number you clown!`;

        }
    }

    function convertM(){
        var miles = (kilometers * 0.621371);
        var kilometers = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
        var answer = document.createElement("H2");
        answer.innerHTML = `${kilometers} kilometers converts to ${miles.toFixed(3)} miles`;
        document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);

        if (isNaN(miles)){
            answer.innerHTML = `Enter a number you clown!`;
        }
    }

    var header = document.querySelector("H1");
    var directions = document.querySelector("P");
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var keyPressed = event.which;
    switch(keyPressed){
        case 77:header.innerHTML = "MILES TO KILOMETERS CONVERTER";
                directions.innerHTML = "Type in a number of miles and click the button to convert the distance to kilometers.";
                km = true;
                console.log(km);
                break;
        case 75:header.innerHTML = "KILOMETERS TO MILES CONVERTER";
                directions.innerHTML = "Type in a number of kilometers and click the button to convert the distance to miles.";
                km = false;
                console.log(km);
                break;
        //default: alert("Please press K or M for conversion");
        }
    });

    var function_ = document.getElementById('convert_btn');
    function_.addEventListener('click',function(params) {
        console.log('imfired');
        if(km == true){        
            convertKM();   
        }
        else{
            convertM();   
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code and it appears that when I switch to Kilometers to Miles by pressing K the form submits but responds as though I have not entered a number. Instead it gives me the message for when someone enters a letter. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: Never mind! I was able to figure it out! I switched the first two variables in convertM() and that solved it. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

One approach you may take is updating a certain flag variable in the same spot you're updating the title and then perform the appropriate calculation, similar to this:

```js
// First conversion function
function convertMilesToKilometers(){
            var miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
            var kilometers = (miles * 1.609344);
            var answer = document.createElement("H2");
            answer.innerHTML = `${miles} miles converts to ${kilometers.toFixed(3)} kilometers`;
            document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);

          if (isNaN(kilometers)){
              answer.innerHTML = `Enter a number you clown!`;
          }
}
// Second conversion function
function convertKilometersToMiles(){
    var miles = (kilometers * 0.621371);
    var kilometers = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
    var answer = document.createElement("H2");
    answer.innerHTML = `${kilometers} kilometers converts to ${miles.toFixed(3)} miles`;
    document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);

    if (isNaN(miles)){
        answer.innerHTML = `Enter a number you clown!`;
    }
}

// Flag variable
var isMiToKm = false;
// Button event handler
function convert() {
    if(isMiToKm) convertMilesToKilometers();
    else convertKilometersToMiles();
}

var header = document.querySelector("H1");
var directions = document.querySelector("P");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var keyPressed = event.which;

    switch(keyPressed){
        case 77:header.innerHTML = "MILES TO KILOMETERS CONVERTER";
                directions.innerHTML = "Type in a number of miles and click the button to convert the distance to kilometers.";
                isMiToKm = true; // Set Mi->Km mode
                break;
        case 75:header.innerHTML = "KILOMETERS TO MILES CONVERTER";
                directions.innerHTML = "Type in a number of kilometers and click the button to convert the distance to miles.";
                isMiToKm = false; // Set Km->Mi mode
                break;
        //default: alert("Please press K or M for conversion");
        }
    });
```

(The code could use some further improvement, but hopefully the concept is clear)